# python custom sort list 1/2/3/../9/10

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list with filenames as follows: `[name1, name10, name11, name2, name3, ..., name9]`.

I want it to be sorted like `[name1, name2, name3, ..., name10, name11]`.

How can I do this?

I know that I can use a special key function (`sorted(files, key=lambda name: etc.)`), but I am not sure which function to apply.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: duplicate: "Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: You have inconsistent spaces in names, are they correct?

Comment: sorry my bad. it's updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a lambda expression to use with the `sorted` function and know that your entries are of the form "nameXXXXX":

```
sorted(names, key=lambda name: int(name[4:]))
```

Comment: Nice! Well, it's the simplest solution if you know exactly what kind of values you'll be dealing with

Comment: But this one won't work in general , . like if a element containing Namea instead of Name .. Check the Below post for a Generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try third party library for **natural string sorting** called `natsort`.

```
>>> import natsort
>>> my_list = [...]
>>> natsort.natsorted(my_list)
```

You can also specify key for sorting using `key` argument.

```
>>> natsort.natsorted(my_list, key=lambda x: ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
sorted(aList, key= lambda x: (lambda a, _, b: (a, int(b)) if b.isdigit() else (float("inf"), x))(*x.partition(" ")))
```

This will work as per your requirement. Also it doesn't require any third party library .

Answer (score 2):

What you search for is [The alphanum algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) (sometimes also called Natural Sort). The site I linked has implementations in multiple languages, even one in [python](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.py).

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

l = ["name1", "name10", "name 11", "name2"]
convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
print sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)
```

Output: `['name1', 'name2', 'name10', 'name 11']`

Comment: you may use `findall` install of split.

Answer (score 1):

i think i got it.
given a list `[name1, name10, name11, name2, name3, ..., name9]`

```
sorted(list, key = lambda name: int(name[4:]))
```

It strips `4` characters because `name` is `4` characters long and then sorts by the remaining numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of code that does the job. It is not optimal but it is easy to understand and gives you an insight on the logic behind the solution of this specific sorting problem.

```
mylist = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name10', 'name11']
sorted_list = []

for n in range(100): #this gives you the order
    for item in mylist:
        if int(item[4:]) == n:
            sorted_list.append(item)

print(sorted_list)
```

It will output:

```
['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name10', 'name11']
```